# Toggle Collapse CSS issue

Tags: css, asp.net

I am having an issue in CSS where I am not able to re-collapse my mobile menu after it's initially been opened. I can't seem to track the issue down.

You can inspect the CSS and function here: http://www.whatshoulditraintoday.com/

Could someone please provide a valid explaination of what's going on here so that I may learn and fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Please check the [help] for info on what an MCVE is and work to add one to your post. It will be much easier to help you then!

Comment: i have no idea what part of that site is broken. Can you provide some code and expected behavior with steps to reproduce the undesired behavior?

Comment: compare with this bootstrap example to find your error http://www.bootply.com/lbIb5ZaHbq can't help

Comment: To produce: Reduce your window to below 768px, so that the mobile menu appears. Open said mobile menu, try and close said mobile menu, this will fail.

Comment: CY5, that does not seem to have a mobile menu that appears. The main website that provides the example does, but the example provided does not.

Comment: BTW, MCVE stands for Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the navigation bar doesn't re-collapse is because you load Bootstrap's files two times in your page. One regular and one minified version.

```
<!-- In head -->
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- In body -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Remove one version and it will re-collapse as expected.

Comment: How silly of me! What was the best way to find this out so I can avoid doing something silly like this again? I am still learning about web development :)

Comment: First thing I did was looking in the structure of the related elements and they looked good. Then I looked at DevTools to see what's going on when I press the collapse `button`. I saw it tries to change the collapsible element but clears everything back immediately (You can see it in DevTools although the view doesn't update). It looked as something tries to update and another thing tries to update back. Since it relies on bootstrap classes and code only, I looked for duplication there. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Fantastic. I appreciate your explaination. I'll keep an eye out for a rookie mistake like this again!